# How to update BloC current state inside of grand children widget

Tags: flutter, bloc, state-management

I have a BloC which its is typical bloc management that it is handling Firebase Cloud Store fetching stuffs. And I have a widget that is ServicesToolView. Here it is a fraction of my code:

```
body:  BlocProvider<ToolFetchServicesBloc>(
                create: (context) =>
                    sl()..add(ToolFetchServicesListEvent(operationModel: operation)),
                child: BlocConsumer<ToolFetchServicesBloc, ToolFetchServicesState>(
                  listener: (context, state) {},
                  builder: (context, state) {
                    if (state is ToolFetchServicesSuccess) {
                      if (state.servicesList.isNotEmpty) {
                
                        return ServicesListWidget(
                            servicesList: state.servicesList,
                            operationModel: operation);
                      } else {
                       
                        return _AddServiceWidget(operationModel: operation);
                      }
                    } else if (state is ToolFetchServicesFailure) {
                      return CustomErrorWidget(
                          errorMessage: state.failure.message,
                          statusCode: state.failure.statusCode);
                    } else {
                      return const LoadingIOSIndicator();
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ),
```

side ServicesListWidget i have a listviewBuilder which we could show services names and other properties in UI. Here is a fraction code of ServicesListWidget:

```
 ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: servicesList.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Container(
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Text(servicesList[index].serviceName.toString()),
                          IconButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                  Navigator.of(context)
                                    .push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (c) => EditServiceWidget(
                                    operationModel: operationModel,
                                    servicesModel: service,
                                  ),
                                ));
                              },
                              icon: const Icon(Icons.add)),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
```

Here where the problem is begun. In this listview I have a button to navigate to edit service screen. My EditServiceWidget wrapped by a cubit and contains bunch of TextField and one save button. Save button perfectly does its job. I use this cubit for managing edit proccess. I mean I have a BlocConsumer and  I pressed the save button and it listens Cubit state and if it is CubitStateSuccess, it ran this code:

```
context.read<ToolFetchServicesBloc>().add(ToolFetchServicesListEvent(operationModel: operation);
```

(don't mind operationModel) But this code excuse me an error:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<ToolFetchServicesBloc> above this BlocBuilder<ToolFetchServicesBloc, ToolFetchServicesState> Widget....
```

It is a classic BlocProvier error. I know how to figure it when you want to listen or consume a Bloc. You can wrap BlocProvider your widget or app before listen. But in this situation I need to access my already existing BloC and I need to call some event it has.

I would be more specifically, I have to call an event from already provided bloc.

`ServicesToolView` >  `ServicesListWidget` > `EditServiceWidget`

I need to access ToolFetchServicesBloc inside EditServiceWidget but not using provide it again because i know every BlocProvider has their own state.

What have I tried?
I tried to use `Navigator with BlocProvider.of...` but it does not work properly.

Thanks you in advance

Answer (score 0):

As i understood you open a new page and in this new page you don't have access to the BLoC. **Only blocs that are provided above MaterialApp are available across routes.**

Pass your BLoC to your new page as a constructor parameter. So you basically need to give your EditServiceWidget a variable of type ToolFetchesServiceBloc.

You can read more about it here: https://bloclibrary.dev/#/recipesflutterblocaccess?id=route-access